# How to train an object detection model with objects in xml files?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection

I have a few images and the xml files associated with the object of that image.

I want to train a model with those images with xml file for object detection.

How to do it using keras or tensorflow.

Some jupyter notebook/github links will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is a type of vague question. You may be talking about object detection algorithm like  Yolo Algorithm. Yolo algorithm along Darknet uses XML for annotation here. If so go through the paper.